# How to handle dependencies with requireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

This is what my config.js file looks like:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '../',
    paths: {
        jQuery:            'js/jquery-1.10.2.min',
        uiEffectsCore:     'js/jQueryUIEffectsCore',
        //Handlebars:        'js/handlebars',
        SyntaxHighlighter: 'js/syntaxhighlighter/scripts/shCore',
        shXml:             'js/syntaxhighlighter/scripts/shBrushXml'
    },
    shim: {
        jQuery: {
            exports: 'jQuery'
        },
        uiEffectsCore: {
            deps: ['jQuery']
        },
        shXml: {
            deps: ['SyntaxHighlighter']
        }
    }
});

require(['js/main']);
```

Then my main.js looks like this:

```
define(function(require){

    require('jQuery');
    require('uiEffectsCore');
    require('SyntaxHighlighter');
    require('shXml');

});
```

I think the problem is that there is no `define(...)` wrapper around my shXml file... I am wondering if I can make this work without having to use that wrapper. Maybe an export shim would do it.

As it stands now, i get [this error](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded) every time.

This question has also been asked [here on github.](https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/SyntaxHighlighter/issues/148)

Comment: The problem is that the library you're using is not AMD-compatible. You have manually specify and load all dependencies in advance to get your code to work.

Comment: @RobW For sure, thats what im doing now, just leaving the syntaxhighlighter stuff in regular script tags before my require.js script

Comment: I believe that you can put the dependencies in the `shim.shXml.deps` array, see http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html

Comment: @RobW updated question, still no luck

Comment: Your previous format of main.js was better. Keep in mind that requireJS cannot magically solve all dependencies synchronously. You have to specify all dependencies in the dependency array; RequireJS will resolve all dependencies and finally invoke the function at the end of `require`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check out this article](https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/SyntaxHighlighter/issues/62), also from github. I tested this, and it works great, but you have to replace the first line of your brush.js files (inside syntaxhighlighter) with this line here:

```
SyntaxHighlighter = SyntaxHighlighter || (typeof require !== 'undefined'? require('shCore').SyntaxHighlighter : null);
```

I don't even know why that fixes the issue, but it does, and you can load your scripts like this:

```
define(function(require){

    require('jQuery');
    require('uiEffectsCore');
    require('SyntaxHighlighter');
    require('shXml');
    require('shCss');
    require('shJs');
    require('Raphael');
```

And you need a shim in your config for dependencies:

```
 paths: {
        SyntaxHighlighter: 'js/syntaxhighlighter/scripts/shCore',
        shXml:             'js/syntaxhighlighter/scripts/shBrushXml',
        shCss:             'js/syntaxhighlighter/scripts/shBrushCss',
        shJs:              'js/syntaxhighlighter/scripts/shBrushJScript'
    },
    shim: {
        shXml: {
            deps: ['SyntaxHighlighter']
        },
        shCss: {
            deps: ['SyntaxHighlighter']
        },
        shJs: {
            deps: ['SyntaxHighlighter']
        }
    }
```